# Cleaning Analytics URLs

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have web Analytics data containing URLs of pages visited on a website that I maintain. Most of the URLs are displayed as they appear in the browser's address bar when on the website i.e., [www.webdomain.co.uk/section/pagename](http://www.webdomain.co.uk/section/pagename). I will refer to this as the 'standard URL'.

However, some of the URLs originate via newsletter clicks, so have numbers, letters and other characters after the 'standard URL' i.e., [www.webdomain.co.uk/section/pagename/g?vx23..](http://www.webdomain.co.uk/section/pagename/g?vx23..).

The 'standard URL' is contained within the longer URL.

I would like a way to clean the extra information off of these URLs, so that I have the 'standard URL' only.

There are too many URLs to manually remove the extra information from each one.

Please can you suggest a method to do this, either via transformations in Excel or Power Query, or by another programme that may be better suited?

I have tried retaining only characters before a given character, such as the final "/", as I noticed that in the majority of cases, the extra information does not contain a slash "/". However, there some instances where there are slashes contained in the extra information that I want to remove, so in some cases the extra information was not completely removed as I had wanted.

I have also tried an Excel formula to collect the domain, however this only collects [www.webdomain.co.uk](http://www.webdomain.co.uk) - it loses the /section/pagename part that I also need.

The /section/pagename parts are not a standard length e.g., in some instances there are multiple sub-sections: [www.webdomain.co.uk/section/subsection1/subsection2/pagename](http://www.webdomain.co.uk/section/subsection1/subsection2/pagename), whereas in others only a pagename. As such, formulae to retain a certain number of characters do not work.

Comment: You want everything before the question mark character? How would you do this manually

Comment: You could split the URL string on a question mark and return the first part: `=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"?"), 1)`

Comment: This has worked - thank you for your help.